# How to show "Add to compare" button in views using "dynamic properties" module in d7?

Tags: 7, views

I need to list the products to compare using views. I have used "Dynamic Properties" module to compare the products.

On each product node I can see a "Add to compare" button. But how to show this button in views?

I've referred this demo site
http://p.worldempire.ch/products

Comment: Do you want it to be avaliable in views fields display, or is it enough in leads display?

Comment: whatever.that button is displaying as form.so i've rendered the form in view field.That's also not working.

Answer (score 1):

It will not support by views at the moment, see the [Issues](http://drupal.org/project/issues/properties?categories=All) for Dynamic properties.

Check this also http://drupal.org/node/1852656

Answer (score 0):

I want this feature too,and finally use this method
I am used php views field to achieve this job,first add nid field to list of field, exclude it from display then add php field ,in  php value field I wrote

```
<?php
$node=node_load($row->nid);
 print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('properties_compare_add_form_node_' . $node->nid, 'node', $node)) 
?>
```

and work correctly for me.